# click on a link from a list of drop down links

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

```
<span class="allMnuHdr">Marketing</span> 
<a href="index.php?module=Campaigns&action=index&parenttab=Marketing" class="allMnu">Campaigns</a> 
<a href="index.php?module=Accounts&action=index&parenttab=Marketing" class="allMnu">Accounts</a> 
<a href="index.php?module=Contacts&action=index&parenttab=Marketing" class="allMnu">Contacts</a> 
<a href="index.php?module=Webmails&action=index&parenttab=Marketing" class="allMnu">Webmail</a>
```

I am trying to click a link within a link. In this case, when I hover the mouse on the link, I'll see a list of links & I want to click on one of those. I've tried many a few things, but no luck.

From the above HTML code, you can see "Marketing" is a parent link & it has some more links within. I want to click on "Accounts" after hovering the mouse on "Marketing".

I've tried `getRoproperty("allitems")` method & that doesn't return anything. While I record the script, I can see the reference to child link as below:

```
Browser("admin - My Home Page -").Page("admin - My Home Page -").Link("Accounts").Click
```

Object spy utility can't be used as links are displayed only when mouse cursor is hovered. Post recording, OR shows accounts as link. I can't get this working using dynamic scripting. Can you please suggest an approach this can be worked in UFT?

Comment: Do not duplicate questions on multiple platforms. If the question belongs to the other site, that's where it will get its response.

Comment: Super User is a question and answer site for **computer enthusiasts and power users**. I don't think you'll get the answer there. Take some extra effort and post the whole question here.

Comment: Edit your question and the information in there.

Comment: What is the properties of `Accounts` link in OR when you record the script?

Comment: Post recording, OR shows accounts as link

Comment: And that's what you want click right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cause the *Marketing* link to display the other links, unfortunately UFT's `Link` object doesn't have a `Hover` function.

Does clicking on *Marketing* work as well as hovering? (How does it work on mobile devices?).

If not you can try using `FireEvent` with `"mouseover"` to try to simulate the event.

Comment: Then accept the answer, that would have saved me some minutes.